# Origen de la conjunción copulativa "y"

Tags: historia, conjunciones, latín

Mi lengua materna es el español, hablo también francés y hace unos días estuve en Italia.

Me he dado cuenta de que tanto en francés como en italiano, la principal conjunción copulativa (lease la traducción de 'y') es "et" y "e" respectivamente.

Incluso estoy leyendo un libro de historia de México y en transcripciones de cartas se observa que hace un par de siglos, incluso en castellano la conjunción copulativa era "e" siempre.

Hoy en día únicamente se usa la "e" cuando la siguiente palabra comienza con "i" por ejemplo:

> Me gusta comer peras e higos.

De lo contrario se dice:

> Me gusta comer peras y manzanas.

¿Alguien sabe cuándo se cambió el uso de la "e" como conjunción copulativa por la "y" y se crearon las reglas actuales, y cuáles fueron las razones para que se cambiara, tomando en cuenta que pareciera que el resto de las lenguas que derivan del latín conservan la conjunción original que era "et"?

Comment: En castellano, los idiomas, nacionalidades, gentilicios... no se escriben con mayúscula. ¡Buena pregunta!

Comment: Tal vez les interese saber que el signo ampersando (&) también surgió de la escritura del "et" latino. En http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26 se ve la evolución del dibujo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pues parece ser que es a causa de las abreviaturas de "et" en los escritos medievales y que no se fijó su uso como copulativa (en lugar de "i") hasta 1726. En el enlace de [Etimologías de chile: origen de la letra Y](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?Y) está explicado.

> En la Edad Media la producción de documentos escritos, como ya sabemos, era manual y para agilizar los procesos de copia y transcripción se empleaban abreviaturas.
>
> Para representar la conjunción coordinante copulativa procedente del latín "ĕt" los amanuenses emplearon varias alternativas gráficas en castellano: la forma latina "et", la arcaica "e", la forma innovadora "i", pero principalmente abreviaturas parecidas al signo "&" con algunas variantes en que se dejaba entrever con mayor o menor claridad la e y la te. La simplificación llevó a que ese signo se llegase a convertir en un trazo similar a una erre minúscula o una i sin punto o bien a un 7 con el borde superior izquierdo curvado hacia arriba, por otro lado muy semejante a una "y" más o menos a mediados del s. XII.
>
> Cuando la imprenta llegó a España, en 1472, ya se había generalizado el empleo tanto de la i latina como de la griega porque la pronunciación general ya debía de ser /i/ entonces. Los impresores seguían empleando abreviaturas consagradas por el uso y, a efectos tipográficos, aquel signo parecido al 7 ya se había convertido precisamente en una "y", porque además de economizar tipos se pronunciaba igual.
>
> Ello no implica que aún triunfara la propuesta. Seguir imprimiendo abreviaturas llegó a no tener demasiado sentido, sobre todo si conllevaba tener que escoger entre demasiados tipos de tipos (valga la redundancia) y ya era preferible escribir las palabras enteras. Hasta 1726 fueron alternándose los usos de "i" e "y" según el impresor o el autor. La RAE zanjó el problema escogiendo la forma actual.

Answer (score 6):

1º) El origen del & es un nexo formado por las formas antiguas de la e y de la t que tiene su origen en la "escritura carolina", un tipo gráfico utilizado en Europa entre los siglos IX y XII y que, por tanto, se usó para la conjunción latina "et". Será sustituido por el signo tironiano a partir del siglo XIII, aunque reaparecerá en el Renacimiento, por la imitación de la escritura carolina que hicieron los humanistas italianos.

2º) El signo similar a un 7 que se utilizó en la Edad Media procede del sistema taquigráfico romano o signos tironianos y se utilizaba para la conjunción latina "et". El uso del signo tironiano se generalizó en la época de la "escritura gótica", es decir, en el siglo XIII y sustituyó a lo que los franceses llaman *peruette* (&).

3º) En los siglos XIII, XIV y XV se utiliza el signo tironiano con el valor de "et" en los textos latinos y con el valor de "e" en los textos romances (asturleonés, gallego y castellano). Cuando no se utiliza ningún signo, en los textos en romance se emplea la "e" con dicho valor.

4º) La "y" como conjunción copulativa empieza a utilizarse a finales del siglo XV en la escritura castellana conocida como "letra cortesana", que fue la grafía oficial de la cancillería de los Reyes Católicos, aunque la "e" (y su correspondiente signo de abreviación en las escrituras cortesana y procesal) estaba mucho más extendida.

5º) A partir de este momento, convivirán las formas e, y, i, como conjunciones copulativas, si bien la "i" se utiliza sobre todo en los siglos XVII, XVIII y XIX. En el XVIII se funda la Real Academia de la Lengua y se inicia el proceso de regulación ortográfica del español que todavía no ha concluido. Para los orígenes gráficos de dicha conjunción deben ustedes consultar libros de Paleografía Española, como por ejemplo el *Tratado* de Agustín Millares Carlo. No es del todo exacto lo que cuenta el comentarista anterior.