# ¿Muestra la imagen un ejemplo de signo tironiano?

Tags: historia, escritura

La siguiente imagen muestra la página de tasación del vocabulario español-latino de Nebrija (1495):

[image: Tasación]

En esta imagen aparece varias veces la que sería la conjunción actual "y", pero escrita de una forma que no reconozco. Comparándola con otras grafías, no es una "e", ni una "i", ni una "y". Según las respuestas a la pregunta sobre [el origen de la conjunción copulativa "y"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2847/12637), y dadas las fechas, parece que podría ser el [signo tironiano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) que mencionan, pero tampoco estoy muy seguro de que eso se parezca a un "&" o a alguna de sus variantes.

Así pues, ¿se muestra en la imagen un signo tironiano? ¿O es alguna otra grafía? ¿Podría ser un ejemplo del "7 con el borde superior izquierdo curvado hacia arriba" que se menciona en la respuesta aceptada?

Comment: La [wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#Probable_evoluci.C3.B3n_del_grafema) dice que proviene de la ípsilon. Con algo de imaginación, _υ_ podemos decir que se parece al carácter que vemos en esta imagen.

Comment: Could it just possibly be the kai symbol? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kai_(conjunction) It would have the right meaning but ...

Comment: Acá lo tenés → https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_tironiana#Historia . Aparentemente en irlandés se sigue usando (!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, es un *et* tironiano (⁊), y débese leer normalmente como *e* aunque tampoco sería incorrecto leerse como *y* ya que sobre todo hacia finales del siglo XV no es imposible encontrar textos que escriben explícitamente *e* o *i/y* para la conjunción).  El *⁊* es bastante frecuente en la tipografía en los incunables y los textos al principio del siglo XVI, pero pronto se dejó de usar y por lo tanto es raro encontrarlo en textos a partir de mediados del siglo XVI.